# Removing item from RecyclerView not working well

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I didn't customize anything on RecyclerView so there's default animation on item added/removed. While I found the animation isn't working as I expected. When I removed item by the following code:

```
mComments.remove(position);
notifyItemRemoved(position);
```

I see on UI it always remove the wrong one, and the one should be removed already keeps showing up and overlay the others.

```
new CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {
    @Override
    public void onTick(long l) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mComments.size(); i++) {
            RoomMessage item = mComments.get(i);
            item.timeRemaining -= 1000;

            if (item.timeRemaining <= 0) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Going to remove no." + i + ". And the content = " + mComments.get(i).text);
                removeAt(i);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        start();
    }
}.start();
```

According to log, I did remove the right one. See as below.

```
02-16 15:26:38.274 21861-21861/com.xxxx.android V/ChatsAdapter: Going to remove no.0. And the content = 1
02-16 15:26:41.284 21861-21861/com.xxxx.android V/ChatsAdapter: Going to remove no.0. And the content = 2
02-16 15:26:42.284 21861-21861/com.xxxx.android V/ChatsAdapter: Going to remove no.0. And the content = 3
```

What did I do wrong?

btw I've set `setisRecyclable(false)`

Answer (score 0):

Use only `notifyItemRemoved(position);`.You are using both. `notifyItemRemoved` which is for notifying that items previously located at position has been removed from the data set. While `notifyItemRangeChanged(int positionStart, int itemCount)` is used only when notify any registered observers that the itemCount items starting at position positionStart have changed. If you are adding single item use `notifyItemInserted`. If you have added more then one new items then use `notifyItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount)`. Any method ending with **Changed** states that the value or values of that particular item or row has changed.

Comment: Updated. It's quite weird that according to log I did remove the correct one while on screen it always remove the wrong one...

Comment: @Dayo Choul so my answer didn't help you? Also you can post the logs. I answered for animation.

Comment: the question has been updated and I also paste the log

Comment: You must be rempving item from lit also. mComments. If so then the list shifts by one position up and item that is removed from list is always at position 0. Also mComments.size() is dynamically calculated which shifts the item by always.

Comment: Sorry I don't get it. Could you explain it in the other way?
btw it's normal that it's always the item with index 0 being removed cuz the latest is always inserted from bottom.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135833/discussion-between-dayo-choul-and-anurag-singh).